# Reg FLASK Environment setup and Virtual Environment setup

Tags: python, flask

I am currently running the latest version of python 3.8.2 in my machine , will the flask will be compatible with this latest version ?

And i am confused with the virtual Environment setup, why we need to setup an environment again when we have flask setup already ?

Comment: @Slvaperumal, please look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, to improve your question as it needs more details

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, before posting questions here, its always advisable that you should do your ground works. So, for the compatibility, you can try and check (let me know). And, virtual environment is not required.

Comment: There are far better places to find an answer to that first question than on Stack Overflow, and the second seems too broad. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Virtual Environments is important. By default, you'll be using your system's python. When you have multiple projetcs you may need to use different versions of some lib or even python, using venv's allow you to have a unique python per project(actually per venv), avoiding compatibilty issues and unecessary headaches.

Yes, Flask will run in Python 3.8.2, it runs in 3.3+( https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/python3/ ).

Hope it helps.